# How to remove Microsoft Login Items after installing Edge?

Tags: login, trash, microsoft

I tried installing Edge to play with the new Bing chat a while ago and now I'm constantly attacked by these notifications

[image]

I see the following when checking my login items:

[image]

I've moved Edge to the trash and emptied the trash but it seems there's some leftover config. How can I clean this up?

Comment: Kinda. I found two micorosft plist items under /Library and an EdgeUpdater app under ~/Library/Microsoft. Let me remove all of those and restart.

Comment: actually yes, that worked!